# Multiple UISwitches To Turn On/Off

Tags: uiswitch

I am new to swift and attempting to place 5 UISwitches on one View Controller.  I would like each one to turn the other 4 (or other 1) switches off.  I am having a pretty rough go of figuring this one out..  Each one I have named with a label of switch1, switch2, etc. through 5.  However, when i type switch1 into the ViewController.swift the variable is not recognized.  I assumed I'd be able to type switch1.enabled = false or something to that effect but I only get an error indicating switch1 is not recognized.  Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing wrong, if you want use switch in controller you must create outlet in view controller.

e.g.

```
   class SwitchDemo: UIViewController{

        @IBOutlet weak var switch1: UISwitch!
        @IBOutlet weak var switch2: UISwitch!
        @IBOutlet weak var switch3: UISwitch!
        @IBOutlet weak var switch4: UISwitch!
        @IBOutlet weak var switch5: UISwitch!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

    }

// Create Switch Toggle Action
     @IBAction func onClickSwitch1(_ sender: Any) {
            if self.contactSwitch.isOn {
                self.switch2.isOn = false
                self.switch3.isOn = false
                self.switch4.isOn = false
                self.switch5.isOn = false
            }else {

            }
        }

    }
```